# timeit on a python file that launches pytest

Tags: python, pytest, timeit

I would like to timeit a python file, but I can't make it work:
the python file looks like this (it launches tests):

```py
import pytest

retcode: int | pytest.ExitCode = pytest.main()

if retcode == pytest.ExitCode.OK:
    print(f"\n---\nAll good\n---\n")
```

I've tried `python -m timeit unit_tests.py` with quotes around the `unit_tests.py` and without extension, and all sort of combinaisons but nothing works.

Traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\timeit.py", line 326, in main
    number, _ = t.autorange(callback)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\timeit.py", line 224, in autorange
    time_taken = self.timeit(number)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lhott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
    unit_tests.py
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'unit_tests' is not defined
```

If I do `python unit_tests.py`, it does work, so I'm in the right directory.

Answer (score 1):

The [timeit command line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface) does not expect a file as input, it expects a string.  The `NameError` is the result of Python trying to execute the filename as a string:

```bash
$ python -c 'test.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

If you want to pass a file you will need somehow provide the file contents as a string parameter; this can be done using command substitution in a bash shell, I'm not sure how you would do this in Windows.

```bash
$ echo 'a = 1 + 1' > test.py
$ python -m timeit test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/timeit.py", line 326, in main
    number, _ = t.autorange(callback)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/timeit.py", line 224, in autorange
    time_taken = self.timeit(number)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
    test.py
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
$
$ $ cat test.py
import  time
time.sleep(1)
$ python -m timeit  "$(cat test.py)"
1 loop, best of 5: 1 sec per loop
```

Note that there are specialised packages for timing pytest suites, such as [pytest-benchmark](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-benchmark/) and [pytest-timeit](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeit/) that may be more suitable than standard timeit, which is designed for small code snippets, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Piping the file in sounds perfect. But I think `cat unit_tests.py | python -m timeit` somehow doesn't work because it displays `50000000 loops, best of 5: 7.02 nsec per loop` when my tests actually takes several seconds to go through. I'm a bit confused as to why

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be: `echo 'import time; time.sleep(1)' > test.py` and `cat test.py | python -m timeit` which outputs `50000000 loops, best of 5: 7 nsec per loop`

Comment: My bad, timeit is looking for a positional parameter, not reading from a stream.  I've amended the answer.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/289344/1001855) might provide some hints for command substitution in Windows (or you may already know how to do it, of course).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's the difference between a positional parameter and reading from a stream. Isn't reading from a stream connecting stdout to stdin of the next function? And the stdin being the parameters of this next function?

Comment: Also, your command works on windows so I guess no need for a command substitution

Comment: Although, I'm not sure why this doesn't work on my file. Maybe the `;` in my `import time; time.sleep(1)` example made it work. Because I don't have it in my original file (see screenshot or original post), I think it bugs because doesn't recognize the linebreaks (https://i.imgur.com/vIH0wP3.png)

Comment: Actually if I don't use the powershell but bash it works but I know have another error `ERROR: file or directory not found: import pytest` which is weird because when I do `pip freeze` i do have `pytest` (I have `pytest` on all the Python versions on my laptop so it's not that I don't have it on one of the versions)

Comment: I got a SyntaxError if `"$(cat test.py)"` was not enclosed in double-quotes.  I'm not sure _why_, but presumably something to do with how the shell passes the result - perhaps without the quotes it returns a bunch of strings rather than a single string.

Comment: I did enclose it in double-quotes though (I mean I did `python -m timeit "$(cat unit_tests.py)"`?)

Comment: I'd guess that's something to do with the shell

Comment: Any idea how to fix my problem then? :( Sorry I feel a bit stupid but I can't find any way of fixing it

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine, so I can't do more than I have: explain the the problem is that `timeit` requires a string as input, not a file.  Tbh I'm not sure timeit is the right tool for what you are trying to do; it's more for one-liners than for files with possibly large import graphs.

Comment: I ended up doing that `python -m timeit "import pytest; pytest.main(['--ignore=viewers']);"` and it worked perfectly!